# Change css based on all options except first option select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add CSS class based on the option selected. The first option will always be selected on page load, the label should not show. Only on the selection of other options, the label should show

```js
$('#reason option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
    $('.return-select label').addClass("form-select-dropdown");
  } else if ($('.return-select option:first').prop('selected', true)) {
    $('.return-select label').removeClass("form-select-dropdown");
  }
});
```

```css
.form-select-dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row return-select">
  <label class="show-default" for="reason">one</label>
  <select id="reason" name="reason" class="required">
    <option class="testing" value="">Default</option>
    <option value="Three">three</option>
    <option value="Four">Four</option>
    <option value="Five">Five</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You're looping over all the options.  If the last option is not selected, the final operation will be to remove the class, regardless if any of the other options are selected.  Also since you do not have any change/input handler for the select, this will never change after page load

Comment: So if user selects any option except default then it should add class "form-select-dropdown" to the label

Comment: But it won't, because this logic only runs on page load.  If you want to have something done on an event, you have to make an event handler for that.  And you also have to address the logical issue I mentioned with the option looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
$("#reason").change(function(event) {
    //get the selected option when the select changes its value
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    //if there is a value attribute on the selected option, then set the class
    if(selected.val()) {
        $('.return-select label').addClass("form-select-dropdown");
    } else {
        $('.return-select label').removeClass("form-select-dropdown");
    }
});
```

or like our friend said bellow:

```
$("#reason").change(function(event) {   
    if(event.target.value) {
        $('.return-select label').addClass("form-select-dropdown");
    } else {
        $('.return-select label').removeClass("form-select-dropdown");
    }
});
```

Comment: absolutely right, you already have the select value in hands by doing this.value or event.target.value

Comment: so latter code in line 2 checked if a value is empty or not?

Comment: that's right, when the string is empty it will be "considered" as false.